# Что-то странное с этими запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Есть два варианта. Один - пример с простым предложением, а второй - со сложным. Будет ли отличаться постановка запятой и нужна ли она там?

"Представление о том, за что требовалось взяться(,) окончательно выкристаллизовалось".

"Я долго думал над этим вопросом, и вскоре представление о том, за что требовалось взяться(,) окончательно выкристаллизовалось".

Comment: Как вы можете это выговорить?

Comment: Кто каждый вопрос голосует за закрытие, на основании несоответствия правилам? Почему не соответствует?

Comment: Простите, но не совсем понял, о чём вы?

Comment: Кто-то проголосовал, чтоб ваш вопрос закрыть. Возможно, вы не видите, потому что вы новичок. Для закрытия нужно 5 голосов, пока только 1. Я задал вопрос: «Кто проголосовал?». Не вижу причин для закрытия.

Comment: Вы правы: я не вижу, что вопрос хотят закрыть. Тем не менее ответ получил, поэтому, думаю, стоит оставить вопрос. Кому-то обязательно поможет решить аналогичную проблему.

Comment: @Джин Вы не новичок, я уже отвечала на ваши вопросы, но у меня есть к вам замечания. 1. Нечеткая постановка вопросов. 2. Обычно ваши предложения требуют редактирования,  но вас интересуют только знаки. Но если грамматика и стилистика неудачны, то проверять пунктуацию вообще не имеет смысла. 3. При совместной работе важна обратная связь, но, получив ответы, вы никак не реагируете, в том числе не голосуете и не принимаете ответы.  Мы не знаем, что вам понятно, а что нет.

Comment: 4. Сложно понять такую позицию. В конечном счете получается немного пользы –   ни для  вас самих, ни для отвечающих, ни для посетителей форума. Пожалуйста, учтите это, наша совместная работа могла быть более интересной.

Answer (score 2):

После редактирования (грамматика и структура не менялись, только лексика):

1. *Представление о том, **за что нужно взяться**, окончательно прояснилось.*

Сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным внутри главного предложения;выделение запятыми.

2. *Я долго думал над этим вопросом, и вскоре представление о том, **за что нужно взяться**, окончательно прояснилось.*

Сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью.

3. Знаки препинания не меняются при добавлении сочинительной связи.

Answer (score 0):

В обоих случаях *«за что требовалось взяться»* — это простое придаточное предложение в составе сложного.

Чтоб это стало более ясно, можно перестроить высказывания, вынеся внутреннее придаточное предложение в конец:

---

*«Окончательно выкристаллизовалось представление о том, **за что требовалось взяться**».*

*«Я долго думал над этим вопросом, и вскоре окончательно выкристаллизовалось представление о том, **за что требовалось взяться**».*

---

В случае же, когда придаточное предложение, находится внутри главного, оно выделяется запятыми с двух сторон:

> 2. Придаточное предложение, находящееся внутри главного, выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон.
>
> Пример:
> *[В небольшой комнате, (которую занимал Нехлюдов), стоял старый кожаный диван]* (Л. Толстой).
>
> [[yaklass.ru](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/11-klass/slozhnoe-predlozhenie-11629/slozhnopodchinennoe-predlozhenie-s-odnim-pridatochnym-10956/re-b42184fd-fafb-4c0c-8693-71fe3164ca92)]

---

Правильно:

*«Представление о том, за что требовалось взяться, окончательно выкристаллизовалось».*

*«Я долго думал над этим вопросом, и вскоре представление о том, за что требовалось взяться, окончательно выкристаллизовалось».*

Comment: "Более ясные" примеры в конце звучат не по-русски.

Comment: @grizzly Это да. Нельзя настолько рассоединять "представление о том", это как стилистическая ошибка.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к критикам. Более того, полагаю, что это тянет даже на ошибку синтаксическую.

Comment: @grizzly Это не имеет отношения к сути вопроса. Задача перестановки слов была в том, чтоб одно предложение перестало находиться внутри другого. Показать, что это просто два простых предложения соединены в сложное. Я написал «чтоб это стало более ясно», т. е. то, о чём я говорю, а не смысл предложений стал более ясным. Так что не перекручивайте: «более ясными» я эти предложения не называл.

Comment: @oleedd Спасибо за замечание. Я этому значения не придал. Моя задача была вынести внутренне предложение как бы наружу, чтоб одно предложение перестало находиться внутри другого. Показать, что это просто два простых предложения соединены в сложное. Предложения изменил, соединив «представление о том».

Comment: @oleedd Спасибо за правку.

Comment: @Eagle Тут есть интересный и сложный момент. Данное простое предложение является частью сложного. А утверждение "*это простое предложение, которое находится внутри сложного*" означает, что и без простого предложение сложное, а это не так.

Comment: @oleedd Да, вы правы. Спасибо, что обратили внимание. Надо переформулировать. Я подумаю как.

Comment: @oleedd Переделал.

Answer (score 0):

В обоих случаях запятая нужна. Придаточное заканчивается словом "взяться" и никаких причин для отступления от общего правила не просматривается.
Это формальный ответ на формальный вопрос.

Что касается необходимости стилистического редактирования, то целиком и полностью поддерживаю. Исходные варианты безусловно корявы, но не настолько, чтобы отказывать им в праве на соблюдение общих правил пунктуации.

Добавлю, что лично мне слово "выкристаллизовалось" само по себе язык не шершавит. Стилистическая проблема в другом: сама структура очень тяжеловесна, синтаксис слишком сложен для выражения такой простой мысли. Правда, у Eagle синтаксис еще хуже.

***После долгого размышления возникло понимание, что надо сделать (или: "с чего начать").***
Тоже можно придраться, но это просто для примера, я вообще не люблю без автора делать кардинальную правку.